# Syntax interpretation for pwrss package in R (power analysis on proportions data)

Tags: r, syntax

I'm having a hard time translating my research question into the correct syntax as the [documentation](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/pwrss/pwrss.pdf) for the pwrss package seems vague. My goal is to calculate the power to detect both a hypothetical future 30% increase and decrease in a proportion (call it 0.5, for example. +/-30% would be = 0.65 and 0.35, respectively), but I'm not sure which test I should use or how to enter the information. For example:

One Proportion against a Constant. p is the "expected proportion" and p0 is a "constant to be compared (also a proportion...)".

```
pwrss.z.prop(p, p0 = 0, margin = 0, arcsin.trans = FALSE, alpha = 0.05, 
alternative = c("not equal","greater","less", "equivalent","non-inferior","superior"), 
n = NULL, power = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
```

Difference between Two Proportions. Here, p1 is the "expected proportion in the first group", while p2 is the "expected proportion in the second group".

```
pwrss.z.2props(p1, p2, margin = 0, arcsin.trans = FALSE, kappa = 1, alpha = 0.05, 
alternative = c("not equal","greater","less", "equivalent","non-inferior","superior"), 
n2 = NULL, power = NULL, verbose = TRUE)
```

The documentation leaves it at that. I've figured out that order matters for pwrss.z.prop, but not pwrss.z.2props. Other than that, I don't know which proportion goes where or what alternative makes sense for my scenario. Both "greater" and "not equal" or "less" and "not equal" seem like the same option: i.e. what power do I have to notice that +30% is "greater" or "not equal" to my original proportion (0.5)(?)

```
library(pwrss)

# Should I be doing
pwrss.z.prop(p=0.5, p0 = 0.65, 
arcsin.trans = TRUE, alpha = 0.05, 
alternative = "not equal",         # or "greater"?
n = 47, power = NULL)

pwrss.z.prop(p=0.5, p0 = 0.35, 
arcsin.trans = TRUE, 
alpha = 0.05, 
alternative = "not equal",         # or "less"?
n = 47, power = NULL)

# or...
pwrss.z.2props(0.5, 0.65, arcsin.trans = TRUE, 
kappa = 1, alpha = 0.05, alternative = "not equal", # or "greater"?
n2 = 47, power = NULL)

pwrss.z.2props(0.5, 0.35, arcsin.trans = TRUE, 
kappa = 1, alpha = 0.05, alternative = "not equal", # or "less"?
n2 = 47, power = NULL)
```

**UPDATE:**

I think `pwrss.z.prop` is the one-sample test and the two-sample test, `pwrss.z.2props`, assumes p1 and p2 are from independent observations. Since mine are paired (increase/decrease of the same data, i.e. repeated measure design), I'll opt for the one-sample version. I've also read that doing two one-sided tests isn't advisable, so all that's left is inputting the +/-30% values in with a two-sided test.

```
pwrss.z.prop(p=0.65, p0 = 0.35, 
arcsin.trans = TRUE, 
alpha = 0.05, 
alternative = "not equal",
n = 47, power = NULL)

 Approach: Arcsine Transformation 
 A Proportion against a Constant (z Test) 
 H0: p = p0 
 HA: p != p0 
 ------------------------------ 
  Statistical power = 0.987 
  n = 47 
 ------------------------------ 
 Alternative = “not equal” 
 Non-centrality parameter = 4.178 
 Type I error rate = 0.05 
 Type II error rate = 0.013 

# Switching p/p0 gives the same answer.

# Here's the problem:
# H0: p = p0 
# HA: p != p0
```

The problem is `HA: p != p0`, which seems to say "we want to know the power to detect a difference between a -30% and +30% change", which is not what I'm looking for. Power for this test is almost 99% with only n=47. This seems to be what it's testing since the magnitude of the difference is so large (0.35 to 0.65), power would naturally be high to detect it. Therefore I'm still stuck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For anyone interested in a possible solution:**
I found out by using a different package that an increase of 30% (or decrease) on a proportion isn't simply a matter of multipling by 0.3 and adding to the original proportion. Instead an arcsin transformation that the `pwr` package uses is necessary.  The function `ES.h() = 2*asin(sqrt(p1))-2*asin(sqrt(p2))` within `pwr.p.test(`) can calculate this effect size, or with a known effect size (in my case) one can calculate the resultant % change value by solving for p1 with `p1 = sin(asin(sqrt(p2))+h/2)^2` or simply `p1 = p2 + h/2`.

Note how this differs from `p1 = p2*0.3 + p2` depending on the starting mean:

```
# effect size formula (h=0.3 effect size)
> 0.5 + h/2
[1] 0.65

> 0.6 + h/2
[1] 0.75


# Standard way of scaling a continuous variable (30% increase):
> (0.5*0.3) + 0.5
[1] 0.65 # same as the effect size method

> (0.6*0.3) + 0.6
[1] 0.78 # Slightly different now!
```

Using the `pwr` package, I see that both a positive and negative effect size result in the same power! The null is we can't tell if a 30% change happened (H0: p1 = p2), while the alternative is we can and it's "greater" than our mean (HA: p1 > p2), or less - makes no difference in terms of power.

```
> pwr.p.test(h = 0.3,  # <- 30% increase effect size
+            n = 47, 
+            sig.level = 0.05,
+            power = NULL,
+            alternative = "greater")

     proportion power calculation for binomial distribution (arcsine transformation) 

              h = 0.3
              n = 47
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.6597727
    alternative = greater

> pwr.p.test(h = -0.3,  # <- 30% decrease effect size
+            n = 47, 
+            sig.level = 0.05,
+            power = NULL,
+            alternative = "less")

     proportion power calculation for binomial distribution (arcsine transformation) 

              h = -0.3
              n = 47
      sig.level = 0.05
          power = 0.6597727
    alternative = less
```